# How do I get the integer part of a double that is represented in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a double value represent as a string. I want get only the integer part of the number as a string

How do I do that?  For example with this string:

```
string str ="123.0000";
```

I want to end up with this string

```
 string result ="123";
```

Comment: could you split it? do you need to parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you want the result as a string, you can just grab `chars` until you encounter a non-digit:

```
string str = "123.0000";
str = new string(str.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could parse it as a double then cast it to an int if you don't need rounding.

```
int i = (int)double.Parse("123.000");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
int integralPart = (int)Double.Parse(str);
```

First you parse the string and create a double and then you cast the double to an integer.

Another way to do so, it would be to split the string based on the dot.

```
var parts = str.Split('.');
```

Then if you want the string representation of the integral part, just get the first item in the array:

```
parts[0]
```

While if you want to create an integer, just parse the latter:

```
int integralPart = int.Parse(parts[0]);
```

For a more proactive style of programming, it would be better you use the `TryParse` method of `double` and `int`, in order to take care of any exception.

For instance:

```
int integralPart;
double number;
if(Double.TryParse(str, out number))
{
    integralPart = (int)number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```
int myInt = (int)Double.Parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use .NET build in functions to make your code as explicit as it can be.

You should parse your number (using Decimal.Parse or Decimal.TryParse) and then use Math.Floor or Math.Truncate function. Which one you'd like to use depends on the way you want to handle negative values.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx

Related functions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx